# LINQ how to use In with numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a  simple LINQ query and I want to implement SQL `in` like functionality in it. I found while googling `Contains(string[])` is an alternate to this.

Please guide me how I use a `in` like functionality in LINQ where clause with `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use contains. Suppose you have a product class like:

```
class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and few elements:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, Name = "Test" });
            products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, Name = "Test" });
            products.Add(new Product { ID = 6, Name = "Test" });
```

Then you can do :

```
        var myProducts = from p in products
                         where productList.Contains(p.ID)
                         select p;
```

This will give you two items with ID 1 and 2, but not the item with ID 6

Answer (score 0):

Use Contains(int[]) the same as your would Contains(string[]). It is an equality issue, not a type issue.

For performance try using a [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx).